# My app is crashing when I add Bluetooth button

Tags: android, button, bluetooth, null

I'm new in Android studio
I want to send data from Arduino to the android via Bluetooth HC-06
I begin my code from the template(Navigation Drawer Activity) of AndroidStudio. 
At first everything was okay, but nightmares begin when I wanted to add Bluetooth button with the help SetOnClickListener to my code.
1. Its appearance changed from this[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQ32O.png)

to this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2pEP.png). For clarity: Navigation bar and other tools disappeared, instead only home fragment is appeared.
2. When push the Bluetooth button on this fragment, my app closed.
 I try to follow logcat , but can't fix the problem.

Please, help me with advice
Best Regard
p.s. Below is my MainActivity.java file

```js
package com.example.myecg2;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.view.View;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer;
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProviders;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;
import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.Set;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;
    private TextView Tekst;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Savollaringiz bo\'lsa Xat yozing", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow,
                R.id.nav_tools, R.id.nav_share, R.id.nav_send)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;

        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_home);
      final BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        Button button =findViewById(R.id.button6);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (btAdapter == null) {
                    Tekst.setText("Bluetooth NOT support");
                    return;
                } else {
                    if (btAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        Tekst.setText("Bluetooth is currently in device discovery process.");

                        Tekst.append("\nPaired Devices are:");
                        Set<BluetoothDevice> devices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                        for (BluetoothDevice device : devices) {
                            Tekst.append("\nDevice" + device.getName() + "," + device);
                        }
                    } else {

                        Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                        startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        );}


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

And the content_main.xml file from the res/layout

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_home"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="394dp"
        android:layout_height="218dp"
        android:text="@string/matn"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button6" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="116dp"

        android:text="@string/LeadI"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_home"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

and errors given in LogCat
2019-11-30 02:09:01.342 13088-13088/com.example.myecg2 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2019-11-30 02:09:01.343 13088-13088/com.example.myecg2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.myecg2, PID: 13088
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.myecg2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:75)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Tekst` is null, i.e. you never instantiate that variable.

Your log says it right here:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference 
at com.example.myecg2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:75) 
at ...
```

It even says the class the error is happening in, `MainActivity`, the method name its happening in `onClick` and the line of the error `:75`.

You are missing doing `findViewById` to instantiate your `Tekst` variable, in the `onCreate` before you attempt to access it (i.e access on line 75).

---

Sidenotes:

you call `setContentView` twice. You should not do that. Delete the second one.

Variable names in Java & Kotlin should start with a lowercase, to help you differentiate them from other things. Rename `Tekst` to `tekst`.  Is that also a typo? perhaps it should be `test` and a better name to help you debug would be `testTextView`.

Comment: But I created (abowe) in line 38 private class Tekst , like this :" private TextView Tekst";

Comment: And the next problem is when I want to run my app to my phone (Xiaomi Redmi 7A) it gives me this error                                                                                   Error: Activity class {com.example.myecg2/com.example.myecg2.MainActivity} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity

Comment: Line 38 is where you declare the variable. You have not instantiated it. i.e. That is you creating a bucket. Now you need to put something in the bucket.